# Github Action to maven build followed by Docker build push

Tags: docker, github-actions

I am a novice with GitHub Actions. I have the below DockerFile

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
RUN addgroup -S spring && adduser -S spring -G spring
USER spring:spring
ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

I am trying to use the GitHub Action [Publish Docker](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/publish-docker) and below is my action code

```
name: Publish Docker
on: [push]
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@master
    - name: Publish to Registry
      uses: elgohr/Publish-Docker-Github-Action@master
      with:
        name: myDocker/repository
        username: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME }}
        password: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_PASSWORD }}
```

The build fails with below error

```
Step 5/6 : COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
COPY failed: no source files were specified
```

I assume it's not able to get the jar file under target folder. Should I add another step for Maven Build before docker build ensure target folder is generated with Jar.

I updated my action as below yet same error

```
name: Build and push Docker images

on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master ]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Set up JDK 1.8
        uses: actions/setup-java@v1
        with:
          java-version: 1.8
      - name: Build with Maven
        run: mvn -B package --file pom.xml
      - uses: actions/checkout@master
      - name: Publish to Registry
        uses: elgohr/Publish-Docker-Github-Action@master
        with:
          name: vinodjayachandran/spring-boot-docker
          username: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME }}
          password: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_PASSWORD }}
```

Refer my repo on git for exact code: https://github.com/vinodjayachandran/spring-boot-docker/

Answer (score 4):

The solution is to have multi stage docker build. Essentially do a maven build from DockerFile and not from GitHub Actions.

My Final DockerFile

```
#
# Build stage
#
FROM maven:3.6.0-jdk-11-slim AS build
COPY src /home/app/src
COPY pom.xml /home/app
RUN mvn -f /home/app/pom.xml clean package

#
# Package stage
#
FROM openjdk:11-jre-slim
COPY --from=build /home/app/target/*.jar /usr/local/lib/app.jar
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/usr/local/lib/app.jar"]
```

GitHub Action :

```
name: Build and push Docker images

on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master ]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@master
    - name: Publish to Registry
      uses: elgohr/Publish-Docker-Github-Action@master
      with:
        name: vinodjayachandran/spring-boot-docker
        username: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME }}
        password: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_PASSWORD }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything looking ok but you must change;

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
RUN addgroup -S spring && adduser -S spring -G spring
USER spring:spring
ENV JAR_FILE=*.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

after you will see work like below.

```
docker build -t deneme:latest .
Sending build context to Docker daemon   2.56kB
Step 1/6 : FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
 ---> a3562aa0b991
Step 2/6 : RUN addgroup -S spring && adduser -S spring -G spring
 ---> Using cache
 ---> ae235df4b0a2
Step 3/6 : USER spring:spring
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 9ac909bf6b8c
Step 4/6 : ENV JAR_FILE=target/*.jar
 ---> Running in 7c8948d44b63
Removing intermediate container 7c8948d44b63
 ---> a26f368cfdba
Step 5/6 : COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
COPY failed: no source files were specified
root@servet:~/denem# ls
app.jar  Dockerfile
root@servet:~/denem# nano Dockerfile
root@servet:~/denem# docker build -t deneme:latest .
Sending build context to Docker daemon   2.56kB
Step 1/6 : FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
 ---> a3562aa0b991
Step 2/6 : RUN addgroup -S spring && adduser -S spring -G spring
 ---> Using cache
 ---> ae235df4b0a2
Step 3/6 : USER spring:spring
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 9ac909bf6b8c
Step 4/6 : ENV JAR_FILE=*.jar
 ---> Running in a78dfae771a0
Removing intermediate container a78dfae771a0
 ---> bdd4cab1bd9c
Step 5/6 : COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
 ---> 9bec1d061268
Step 6/6 : ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
 ---> Running in c23f2ddb682b
Removing intermediate container c23f2ddb682b
 ---> e24407464a2b
Successfully built e24407464a2b
Successfully tagged deneme:latest
```

Comment: I replaced ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar with ENV JAR_FILE=*.jar but still getting the same error. Do we need the maven build steps in the github action? Refer my Github repo https://github.com/vinodjayachandran/spring-boot-docker/

Comment: bu I didn't seen any jar files if you can share full project I can solve error

Comment: Jar file doesn't exist as part of repo. When Maven build succeeds, the jar will be created in target folder. Is it not possible to do maven build first and take the jar on successful build to do docker push ?